# How do you translate "misalignment spacers"?

Tags: translation, simplified-characters, mainland-china

I'm looking for the word for "misalignment spacers", which are mechanical parts for use with Heim joints (鱼眼轴承). Anyone know what they're called in China? Here's a photo. Misalignment spacers are the pair on the right. The left is just a Heim joint. Any mechanics around here?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"High misalignment aluminum spacer" is named [高偏差铝垫片](https://chinese.alibaba.com/product-detail/high-misalignment-aluminum-spacer-60502337456.html).

So, "misalignment spacer" is 偏差垫片.

[image]